# How to use barcode result to open webview in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using BarcodeScanner package. I get the result after scan the QR code. My question is how to use that result then open the website. Here is my code:

```
Future scan() async{
    Completer<WebViewController> _controller = Completer<WebViewController>();
    try {
      String barcode = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
      setState(() {
        this.barcode = barcode;
        print(this.barcode);
    WebView(
    initialUrl: this.barcode,
    onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
      _controller.complete(webViewController);
    },
  ),
      });
      } on PlatformException catch (e) {
        if (e.code == BarcodeScanner.CameraAccessDenied) {
          setState(() {
            this.barcode = 'The user did not grant the camera permission!';
          });
        } else {
          setState(() => this.barcode = 'Unknown error: $e');
        }
      } on FormatException{
        setState(() => this.barcode = 'null (User returned using the "back"-button before scanning anything. Result)');
      } catch (e) {
        setState(() => this.barcode = 'Unknown error: $e');
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Webview here, after you receive QR code from scanner you need you navigate to new screen. Like this

```
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => WebView(initUrl: data[index].homeLink))
  );
```

Otherwise, you can use url_launcher plugin
https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher